# Глобальный перехват паники

Tags: golang

Нужно установить глобальный перехватчик паник. Чтобы вместо стандартной печати пропущенной паники на консоль отправлять stacktrace в лог (или в лог и на консоль или на удалённый сервер или всё вместе), а потом уже самостоятельно завершать работу программы.

Задача - поймать место возникновения паники, которое проскочило мимо recover.

```
package main

import "time"

func handlePanic() {
    // перехватываю панику и получаю стек горутины в которой паника произошла.
    // или всех горутин. Или и то и другое (в идеале)
}

func main() {
    handlePanic()
    go panic(123)
    time.Sleep(time.Millisecond)
}
```

Comment: Я пытался решить эту задачу. Пришел к выводу, что лучший способ это отключить все перехватчики и записывать **cout** в файл. Когда программа падает она всегда пишет стактрэйс в **cout**. Для ubuntu `./exe > log.txt`.

Comment: Я у себя нечто подобное сделал. Только бинарник сам себя еще раз запускает с переадресацией вывода. Это всё равно нужно было делать для демонизации, да и функциональность уже готова.

Answer (score 1):

Панику отлавливать можно только в `defer`, так что так как вы хотите не получится. Но можно завернуть обработку паники в функцию и defer'нуть её:

```
func recoverAll() {
    if err := recover(); err != nil {
        log.Println(err)
    }
}

func main() {
    defer recoverAll()
    panic("Boom!")
}
```

Playground: https://play.golang.org/p/dRu7cnTrwv.

Comment: Этот прием я давно использую, но в данном случае это не поможет: тут или я забыл где-то панику отловить или паника происходит в горутине, которую стартую не я и соответственно defer/recover я для неё сделать не могу. Нужен способ отловить не просто panic(123), а go panic(123) - т.е. что-то запущенное в левой горутине.

Comment: @rekby Теперь ясно. Увы, не думаю, что такое возможно.

Answer (score 0):

На хабре есть [статья](https://habrahabr.ru/post/118898/). В вашем случае будет чуть иначе. Вот так, например:

```
package main

import "fmt"

    func main() {

        defer func() {
            if r := recover(); r != nil {
                fmt.Println("Функция восстановлена ex3", r)
            }
        }()
        example3()
        fmt.Println("Всё хорошо")
    }



    func example3() {
        fmt.Println("Вызов функции ex4")
        example4(0)
        fmt.Println("Функция ex4 завершилась успешно")
    }

    func example4(i int) {
        if i > 3 {
            fmt.Println("Опаньки!")
            panic(fmt.Sprintf("%v", i))
        }
        defer fmt.Println("Завершение функции ex4", i)
        fmt.Println("ex4 ", i)
        example4(i+1)
    }
```

Comment: про recover я в курсе, это используется. Но приложение падает с паникой, видимо в какой-то из горутин, где паника не отлавливается. Может быть в каком-то библиотечном коде. Т.е. моя задача - поймать ту панику, которая выкинулась на самый верх и программа падает уже целиком. Перед падением мне надо написать в лог/отправить на сервер почему программа упала.

Comment: @rekby Если у вас паника не отлавливается recover'ом в main'е, то возможно у вас где-то фатальная ошибка. Обновите вопрос с бэктрейсом, чтобы понять, что именно пошло не так.

Comment: Паника поймается отложенным вызовом, который я привёл. В чём беда?

Comment: Беда в том что этот отложенный вызов ловит только панику в своей горутине, а мне надо поймать панику из той горутины где recover заранее никто не вызвал. Чтобы посмотреть почему падает и почему там recover нету. Добавил пример в вопрос.

Comment: Я пытался решить эту задачу. Пришел к выводу, что лучший способ это отключить все перехватчики и записывать **cout** в файл. Когда программа падает она всегда пишет стактрэйс в **cout**. Для ubuntu `./exe > log.txt`.